# Invert matrix of Fractions with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an n*n matrix like so:

```
[
    [Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(-1, 2)],
    [Fraction(-4, 9), Fraction(1, 1)]
]
```

And I want to find its inverse. Since it has `Fraction`s in it, doing:

```
from numpy.linalg import inv
inv(M)
```

Does not work. I get `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc inv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sympy` we can get results with fractions.

```
2104:~/mypy$ isympy
IPython console for SymPy 1.6.2 (Python 3.8.5-64-bit) (ground types: python)
...

In [2]: from sympy.matrices import Matrix
In [4]: from sympy import Rational

In [5]: Rational(3/4)
Out[5]: 3/4
```

With floats:

```
In [6]: M1 = Matrix([[1/1, -1/2],[-4/9, 1/1]])

In [7]: M1
Out[7]: 
⎡       1.0          -0.5⎤
⎢                        ⎥
⎣-0.444444444444444  1.0 ⎦

In [8]: M1.inv()
Out[8]: 
⎡1.28571428571429   0.642857142857143⎤
⎢                                    ⎥
⎣0.571428571428571  1.28571428571429 ⎦
```

With Rational (fractions):

```
In [9]: M2 = Matrix([[1, Rational(-1,2)],[Rational(-4,9),1]])

In [10]: M2
Out[10]: 
⎡ 1    -1/2⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎣-4/9   1  ⎦

In [11]: M2.inv()
Out[11]: 
⎡9/7  9/14⎤
⎢         ⎥
⎣4/7  9/7 ⎦
```

Check against the float answer:

```
In [12]: M1.inv()*7
Out[12]: 
⎡9.0  4.5⎤
⎢        ⎥
⎣4.0  9.0⎦
```

or

```
In [18]: M2.inv().evalf()
Out[18]: 
⎡1.28571428571429   0.642857142857143⎤
⎢                                    ⎥
⎣0.571428571428571  1.28571428571429 ⎦
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question here:
[Getting No loop matching the specified signature and casting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838306/getting-no-loop-matching-the-specified-signature-and-casting-error)

You could use a `numpy matrix` and specify `dtype=float` (as the suggested answer):

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv

matrix = np.matrix([ [Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(-1, 2)], [Fraction(-4, 9), Fraction(1,1)] ], dtype='float')
inv(matrix)
```

Or you could also use `float` numbers instead of `Fractions`

```py
from numpy.linalg import inv

matrix = [ 
  [1/1, -1/2], 
  [-4/9, 1/1] 
]
inv(matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the answer as floats - I need the answers as fractions.

Comment: One more attempt. Does converting the value of `inv(matrix)` to `Fraction` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42209716/5745962 suit you? (That is, using `float` numbers to compute the `inverse` and then rounding them to the closest `rational`)

Comment: This actually led me to the answer in the end. I just did it this way and re-converted them with `limit_denominator()` in the end. Thanks!

Comment: That's a bit ugly, in that you won't necessarily know what limit to set for the denominator. What you could do is multiply through by the lowest common multiple of the denominators, solve in integers, and divide again.